# infinite loop is not working using loop={true} , enableSnap ={true} list is not scrolling infinte mode in android using react-native-snap-carousel

Tags: react-native

**Actual Behavior**

i m displaying the list in card and the card is not scrolling in the infinite mode it get strucked in middle in android

**Expected Behavior**

Card should be scroll in the infinite mode while scrolling in android

```
<Carousel
         ref={c => {
           this._carousel = c;
         }}
         carouselRef={this.props._slider1Ref}
         data={this.props.data}
         renderItem={this._renderItem}
         sliderWidth={this.props.sliderWidth}
         itemWidth={this.props.itemWidth}
         loop={true}
         loopClonesPerSide={this.props.loopClonesPerSide}
         firstItem={this.props.firstItem}
         onSnapToItem={index => this.onSnap(index)}
         layout={this.props.layout}
         layoutCardOffset={this.props.layoutCardOffset}
         showSpinner={this.props.showSpinner}
         activeSlideAlignment="start"
         useScrollView={false}
         activeSlideOffset={this.props.activeSlideOffset}
         lockScrollWhileSnapping={true}
         enableSnap={true}
         enableMomentum={false}
         activeSlideOffset={this.props.activeSlideOffset}
         decelerationRate="fast"
        // removeClippedSubviews={true}
         removeClippedSubviews={false}
       />
```

Comment: are you swiping too fast ? coz sometimes ive seen that issue too

Comment: no i am not swiping it fast

Answer (score 0):

Go to node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel/src/carousel/Carousel.js and edit line 820

```
 if (nextActiveItem === this._itemToSnapTo && scrollOffset === this._scrollOffsetRef) {
    this._repositionScroll(nextActiveItem);
 }
```

to

```
 if (nextActiveItem === this._itemToSnapTo && Math.trunc(scrollOffset) === Math.trunc(this._scrollOffsetRef)) {
    this._repositionScroll(nextActiveItem);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

While Using this Please keep one thing in mind that don't use the  Simulator for run the Application. In My case it was not working in Simulator, but when I attache the IPhone It was working fine in that case.